# Not able to load core dump fully in gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am trying to load core dump (which is quite big like 30 GB), of a program in gdb, but its not being loaded fully I believe. After a lot of research I could not find any thing relevant so I am asking here. Initially you get warnings for something missing. I am using gdb 8 and 11, both give the same results.

Warnings:

```
Reading symbols from svc...

warning: Can't open file /app/svc during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /SYSVafaf1240 (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /SYSVafaf123f (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /SYSVafaf123e (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /SYSVafaf123d (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /SYSVafaf123c (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /SYSVafaf123b (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /SYSVafaf123a (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /opt/lib64/libpq.so.5 during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /opt/lib64/libresolv.so.2 during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /opt/lib64/librabbitmq.so.4 during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /opt/lib64/libboost_random.so.1.67.0 during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 1]
[New LWP 26]
[New LWP 9]
[New LWP 65]
[New LWP 10]
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
```

And then in backtrace you get something like this, that you can see is not complete.

Back trace Sample:

```
Core was generated by `./service'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004a11b0 in nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, std::vector, std::string, bool, long, unsigned long, double, std::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer>::create<std::string, char const (&) [48]> (args#0=...) at src/commons/nlohmann/json.hpp:11937
11937           std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(deleter)> object(AllocatorTraits::allocate(alloc, 1), deleter);
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 1)]

Thread 49 (LWP 64):
#0  0x00007f53de7ccccd in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 48 (LWP 45):
#0  0x00007f53e0218a35 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 47 (LWP 44):
#0  0x00007f53e0218a35 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 46 (LWP 42):
#0  0x00007f53e0218a35 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 45 (LWP 39):
#0  0x00007f53e0218a35 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 44 (LWP 37):
#0  0x00007f53e0218a35 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

There are multiple threads working when program segfault, which is not possible to know by the backtrace given by the gdb. Can you please help regarding this?

Update:
This coredump.conf file on the machine the core dump is create is this:

```
[Coredump]
#Storage=external
#Compress=yes
#ProcessSizeMax=2G
#ExternalSizeMax=2G
#JournalSizeMax=767M
#MaxUse=
#KeepFree=
```

Is it a issue?

Comment: Are you analyzing the `core` on the same machine on which it was produced?

Comment: No, I get from the server and then compiled the same branch for which that was created, and then I try to load it.

Comment: That's an important point, don't you think?